# primusrun/optirun slower than the default launching

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Today I've noticed something really weird:

**When I execute**

`vblank_mode=0 glxgears`

I get:

> 38885 frames in 5.0 seconds = 7776.864 FPS
>
> 39279 frames in 5.0 seconds = 7855.745 FPS
>
> 39096 frames in 5.0 seconds = 7819.048 FPS

**And wen I execute:**

`vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxgears`

I get:

> 7813 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1562.430 FPS
>
> 8459 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1691.648 FPS
>
> 8464 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1692.777 FPS

So, without primusrun/optirun I'm getting 500% more FPS.
How is this possible?

Does this mean that I'm using my nvidia chipset most of the time and for gaming (the only thing I use `primusrun steam`) I'm using the intel one?

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.

Running `primusrun "command"` will **always** get your nVidia card to render the program, not the other way around.
The issue here is simply that glxgears [is **not** a benchmark](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Glxgears_is_not_a_Benchmark).

You should benchmark with something else. Try [supertuxcart](http://supertuxkart.blogspot.com/) or [xonotic](http://xonotic.org/). Or even better, try an actual game you wish to play.

You pretty much have nothing to fix, at least as far as using the nVidia card is concerned. =-)

Comment: You were rigth, cs:go with primus: 45~55  ,   without: 20~35

Comment: Good thing it's sorted! I had the same experience with glxgears vs Left4Dead2.